# html table must retain pagination post dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table that has 2 columns and dynamic number of rows. 
And a dropdown filter. The filter works fine but when filtered, the table loses its pagination.

```
<div id="bagStatusTable" class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 10px; display: block; width: 100%;">
    <table id="bag_table_id" style="margin-top:10px">
        <thead>...</thead>
        <colgroup>...</colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="bag number" style="font-size:20px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px">1</td>
                <td id="bag_0_status" class="bag status">
                    <i class="fas fa-running fa-2x" style="color: #FFFF00; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fa9e00;"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="bag number" style="font-size:20px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px">2</td>
                <td id="bag_1_status" class="bag status">
                    <i class="fas fa-running fa-2x" style="color: #FFFF00; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fa9e00;"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
            <tr style>...</tr>
        </tbody>    
        <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

filter

```
$("#bagStatusFilter").on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(value == 'all'){
    $('.bagStatusFilter').val('');
    $('#bag_table_id tr').show();
  }
  else{
    $('#bag_table_id tr').hide();
    $("#bag_table_id tr").filter(function() {
       ($(this).toggle($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").children().length > 0 && $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").children()[0].className.includes(value)))
    });

  }  
})
```

Pagination

```
function addPagerToTables(tables, rowsPerPage) {
    tables = 
        typeof tables == "string"
      ? document.querySelectorAll(tables)
      : tables;

    for (let table of tables) 
        addPagerToTable(table, rowsPerPage);
}

function addPagerToTable(table, rowsPerPage) {
    let tBodyRows = table.querySelectorAll('tBody tr');
    let numPages = Math.ceil(tBodyRows.length/rowsPerPage);
    let colCount = 
    [].slice.call(
        table.querySelector('tr').cells
    )
    .reduce((a,b) => a + parseInt(b.colSpan), 0);

    table
    .createTFoot()
    .insertRow()
    .innerHTML = `<td colspan=${colCount}><div class="nav"></div></td>`;

    if(numPages == 1)
        return;

    table.querySelector('.nav')
    .insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend', 
        `<a class="page-link" href="#">&laquo;</a> `
    );

    for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
        let pageNum = i + 1;
        table.querySelector('.nav')
              .insertAdjacentHTML(
                  'beforeend', 
                  `<a class="page-link" href="#" rel="${i}">${pageNum}</a> `
              );
    }


    table.querySelector('.nav')
    .insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend', 
        `<a class="page-link" href="#">&raquo;</a> `
    );

    changeToPage(table, 1, rowsPerPage, numPages);

    for (let navA of table.querySelectorAll('.nav a'))
        navA.addEventListener(
            'click', 
            e => changeToPage(
                table, 
                e.target.innerHTML, 
                rowsPerPage,
                numPages
            )
        );

}

function changeToPage(table, page, rowsPerPage, totalPages) {

    if(isNaN(parseInt(page))){
      page = page === "<<" ? 1 : totalPages
    }

    let startItem = (page - 1) * rowsPerPage;
    let endItem = startItem + rowsPerPage;
    let navAs = table.querySelectorAll('.nav a');
    let tBodyRows = table.querySelectorAll('tBody tr');

    for (let nix = 0; nix < navAs.length; nix++) {

        if (nix == page - 1)
            navAs[nix].classList.add('active');
        else 
            navAs[nix].classList.remove('active');

        for (let trix = 0; trix < tBodyRows.length; trix++) 
            tBodyRows[trix].style.display = 
                (trix >= startItem && trix < endItem)
                ? 'table-row'
                : 'none';  

    }

}
```

I understand that this is because the pagination function sees the table as a whole as opposed to just the filtered rows. 
I tried to return the filtered rows inside the filter function and make the pagination function use that. 
But it did not work.

How to return the filtered rows to an array and use that?

Comment: What are you using for pagination? I don't see where you say that in your question.

Comment: I have added the pagination code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things I noticed.

In `changeToPage`, you're just looping over `table.querySelectorAll('tBody tr')`. That wouldn't take into account rows that have been hidden.

What might be better is, when you're filtering, add or remove a class instead of doing a `.toggle`:

```
$('#bag_table_id tr').each(function() {
  let $this = $(this);
  let match = $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').children().length > 0
    && $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').children()[0].className.includes(value);
  $this.toggleClass('filter-hide', !match);
});
```

Few notes about this:

- You're using `.filter` more like `.each`...better to just use `.each`
- $(this) runs a function every time, more efficient to assign to variable.
- using `.toggleClass` to add/remove class as needed.
- adding `.filter-hide` to the ones that don't match, so that we can use it in `changeToPage` without breaking it when there is no filter
- and of course you'll need to add a css rule for `.filter-hide { display:none; }`

You'll also need a `removeClass` in the `if(value==='all')`:

```
$('#bag_table_id tr').removeClass('filter-hide');
```

Now that class can be added to `changeToPage`

```
let tBodyRows = table.querySelectorAll('tBody tr:not(.filter-hide)');
```

(Because we're using `:not(.filter-hide)`, it will still work if no filter has been applied at all)

Once you've done all that, you'll also need to keep track of your pagination so that you can call `changeToPage` after you do a filter operation...and that should do it!

Comment: Had to change .each to ```$('#bag_table_id tbody tr').each(function() {```
my tfoot has the tr for page number. So it hid that one as well.
It worked after the changed. Thanks a ton!